# How can i adjust my iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to adjust my iframe with one scrollbar and auto height the iframe but i dont know how. How can i do that?. The code is here

```html
<style type="text/css">
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

</style>

<body>

<iframe src='http://www.dohop.com/widget/2/?forms=flights&target=&tabs=top&orientation=horizontal&border_color=808080&text_color=202020&background_color=D0D0D0&form_border_color=808080&form_text_color=000&form_background_color=FAFAFA&width=1000&flang=es&whitelabel=http://vuelos.gangatravel.es/' scrolling='yes' width='1000' height='250' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow: hidden;' allowtransparency='true'>
</iframe>
<div style='text-align: right; width: 1000px; display:block; margin-top:5px;'>
 <a href='http://www.dohop.com' style='font-size:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#007BA4;'></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need vertical scrollbar and auto height at the same time???

Comment: yess but only the main vertical scrollbar

Comment: main vertical scrollbar and auto height, for example if the search results are 50 flights, the height should be "500px", if the results search are 100, the height should be "1000px" but automatically(auto height without put the pixels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just allow the `iframe` taking the full width and hide the `body` overflow. For this, modify your HTML to following,

```
<body>

<iframe src='http://www.dohop.com/widget/2/?forms=flights&target=&tabs=top&orientation=horizontal&border_color=808080&text_color=202020&background_color=D0D0D0&form_border_color=808080&form_text_color=000&form_background_color=FAFAFA&width=1000&flang=es&whitelabel=http://vuelos.gangatravel.es/' scrolling='yes' frameborder='0' style='border:none;' allowtransparency='true'>
</iframe>
<div style='text-align: right; width: 1000px; display:block; margin-top:5px;'>
    <a href='http://www.dohop.com' style='font-size:10px;text-decoration:none;color:#007BA4;'></a>
</div>

</body>
```

And use the following CSS,

```
    iframe{
        min-width:100px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    body{
        overflow:hidden;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }   
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

adding the following to the head section  of the code might solve the problem

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

add this as an atttribute inthe iframe element

```
onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'
```